# Voting to close on the question vs. in the review queue

Tags: bug, review, closing

Thinking this is a bug unless I missed something in the guidelines.

If I click on "review" and vote to close items from there, my badge progress counter increases as expected, and the vote is in my history.

But if I vote to close a question on the question's own page, my counter remains the same.  Also, the vote does not appear in the history.  Is this the expected behavior?